# jQuery window resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
WinSize = $(window).width();
var currentPosition = 0;
var slideWidth = WinSize;

$(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        slideWidth = WinSize = $(window).width();
    });
});    


var slides = $('.slide');
var numberOfSlides = slides.length;

// Remove scrollbar in JS
$('#slidesContainer').css('overflow', 'hidden');

// Wrap all .slides with #slideInner div
slides
.wrapAll('<div id="slideInner"></div>')
// Float left to display horizontally, readjust .slides width
.css({
    'float' : 'left',
    'width' : slideWidth
});

// Set #slideInner width equal to total width of all slides
$('#slideInner').css('width', slideWidth * numberOfSlides);

// Insert controls in the DOM
$('#PageBG')
.prepend('<a href="#" class="control" id="previous"><span>Previous</span></a>')
.append('<a href="#" class="control" id="next"><span>Next</span></a>');

// Hide left arrow control on first load
manageControls(currentPosition);

// Create event listeners for .controls clicks
$('.control')
.bind('click', function(){
    // Determine new position
    currentPosition = ($(this).attr('id')=='next') ? currentPosition+1 : currentPosition-1;

    // Hide / show controls
    manageControls(currentPosition);
    // Move slideInner using margin-left
    $('#slideInner').animate({
        'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-currentPosition)
    },800, 'linear');
});

$('.SlideSelect')
.bind('click', function(){

// Move slideInner using margin-left
$('#slideInner').animate({
    'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-$(this).attr('id'))
},800, 'linear');
```

});

I want slideWidth to change based on the window size so when the window is resized the slideWidth changes but I don't seem to be able to get this to work.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't update other variables, `slideWidth` is a different, distinct variable, a copy of the value in `WinSize` whenever it was set initially, you need something like this in your function to update both:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        slideWidth = WinSize = $(window).width();
    });
});
```

Make sure `slideWidth` is in scope so that this updates the same `slideWidth` variable, and not creating a global one.  Alternatively, just use `WinSize` for your code, there's no need for 2 variables, at least not in your example...maybe there is a need in the rest of your code.

Comment: Sorry could you explain that I'm not too sure

Comment: @Brob - Which part? Your best bet, unless you need another variable, is to just use `WinSize` in your code, *probably* no need for the extra variable that isn't updated.